# Maintaining linear history on GitHub while having 2 permanent branches

Tags: git, github, rebase

I've got a company git Repository up on GitHub that has 10ish Developers working on it full time with merges going all over the place in the past, with features branches being based off and going into develop and hotfix branches being based off and going into main, but making sure the hotfixes are merged back into develop all of the time is a real PITA and leads to commits being in the history several times and a real bowl of spaghetti trying to read the gitlogs, so I'm trying to enforce linear history on it.

I was gonna do this by picking a moment to consider the two branches equal. (By deleting the current develop after a big deploy and creating a new develop branch from main), turning off merge commits (only squash and rebase allowed in the repository) and preferably enforcing linear history.

- Feature branches should be branched off from develop, rebased from develop daily to keep up to date and when the feature is done it should be squashed back into develop.
- Likewise hotfixes should be branched off from main, rebased from main daily (should not be needed as hotfixes are supposed to go fast) to keep up to date and when the hotfix is done it should be squashed back into main.

To make sure the hotfixes make their way into develop and still have linear history, I was going to have develop rebased onto main after every hotfixes, but doesn't this violate the golden rule of rebasing; "Never rebase while you're on a public branch?" therefore potentially causing issues for everyone rebasing doing their daily feature branch rebasing?

Without this though, I can't for the life of me figure out how to enforce linear history with hotfixes on two branches. Anyone who can point out the error of my ways?

Comment: You have your choice of Impossibility A (easy to read tangled branches) or Impossibility B (untangled linear history of something that's fundamentally not linear). [TANSTAAFL](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/tanstaafl.asp)

Comment: It sounds like you are using Git Flow or similar, but if so, this statement should not be true, "leads to commits being in the history several times". That only happens if you aren't merging hotfixes back into `release` (are you using release?) or `develop` fast enough such that someone else duplicates the PR into the other branch.

Comment: Have you tried `git log --first-parent`? This will show you what you would get if you used squash merge, but with the added advantage of still keeping the commit resolution for when you want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

The linear history approach you are trying to implement assumes you are using trunk based development https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com

You will always struggle with this so long as you have two main branches.

The solution is to move to a single main branch, and feature flag your work-in-progress. This actually opens up new possibilities, such as testing in production (which is very valuable), on demand/continuous deployments, etc.